# Eclipse Luna JUnit Source location not found

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Just reformatted my PC and trying to get my JUnit tests to work on eclipse.

When I right click my project > Build Path > Add Libraries, and select JUnit 4 (or 3), it says

> Source Location: Not found.

A few things came up on google but it was suggesting I edit files that I don't have in my eclipse configuration folder, so assume it's to do with older versions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have to reinstall the junit plugin.

[image]

Comment: I'm really confused because I just made a simple test case and it works, but the JUnit path still says Source Location: not found. How do I redownload the plugin?

Comment: I thought my install of Luna 4.4 already came with JUnit. My main eclipse installation is under C:\eclipse, and the plugins directory is under there, and it contains the jar file. Verify your plugins directory and see if the JUnit jar file is there.